# cannot access Oracle Audit Vault server via browser

Tags: oracle

anyone has installed Oracle Audit Vault and Database Firewall, I have installed the vault, but at the interface step like this, I can't see anything.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5729.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3IyF.png) This is what i see